# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_hub'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-hub, modulenotfounderror

I followed instructions given in the TensorFlow website to install tensorflow_hub and installed it within a conda environment.

```
$ pip install "tensorflow>=2.0.0"
$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow-hub
```

I ran the above in anaconda prompt

[image]

But I'm still getting `ModuleNotFoundError` for 'tensorflow_hub'.

Any help here is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: May be your're using multiple environments

Comment: Use `python -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow-hub`, and replace `python` with whichever python interpreter you want to use.

Comment: Hi Abhiram kadali, As Adam suggested, can you please confirm if you are `importing tensorflow hub` in the same `virtual environment` in which you have installed it. Thanks!

Comment: I mean to say, please ensure that you are `importing tensorflow_hub` in your `Virtual Environment`, `py3_TF2.0`. If it is still resulting in error, please share your code.

Answer (score 20):

**First thing**
Check whether you have installed tensorflow_hub within that environment

```
conda list
```

If you can not find it there, maybe you have been installing it to another environment which does not matter, just install it again here.

```
pip install tensorflow_hub
```

**You have probably done that** so most likely you are using another kernel within your jupyter notebook, so either go to the environment of that kernel and install your package there. Or the preferred way, install your current environment `yourenvironment` as a new kernel and use that one in your jupyter notebook

```
  python -m ipykernel install --user --name=yourenvironment
```

**Now start your jupyter notebook and enjoy your package**