# How to use tensorflow hub in Azure ML

Tags: python, azure, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to use  TensorFlow Hub in Azure ML Studio

I am using the kernel Python 3.8 PT and TF

And I installed  a few modules:

```
!pip install bert-for-tf2
!pip install sentencepiece
!pip install "tensorflow>=2.0.0"
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow-hub
```

With pip list, I can see they are installed:

```
tensorflow                              2.8.0
tensorflow-estimator                    2.3.0
tensorflow-gpu                          2.3.0
tensorflow-hub                          0.12.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem            0.24.0
```

However when I try to use it as per the documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/hub)

Then I get the classic:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_hub'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_hub'`  error, try following ways:

- Try installing/upgrading the latest version of `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-hub` and then import:

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow

!pip install --upgrade tensorflow_hub

import tensorflow as tf

import tensorflow_hub as hub
```

- Install the current environment as a new kernel:

```
python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=testenvironment
```

You can refer to [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_hub', No module named 'tensorflow_hub'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63884339/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tensorflow-hub) and [How to use Tensorflow Hub Model?](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/767)